# Skip selenium Webdriver.get() call inside for loop if it takes too long

Tags: python, selenium, loops

Hey guys I'm having trouble understanding how can I add exceptions to a for in range loop. Right now I'm pulling URLs from an excel sheet and scraping the information while moving throughout the pages until I reach page 200. The thing is that not all URLs have pages up to 200 so It's taking a lot of time until the loop ends and program can continue with another URL. Is there a way to implement exceptions in to the code here?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")

companies = []

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/urls.xlsx')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    base_url = (row['urls'])
    
    for i in range(1,201,1):
        
        url = "{base_url}?curpage={i}".format(base_url=base_url, i=i)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a/div/div/p')
    
        for names in name:
            print(names.text, url)
            companies.append([names.text, url])
```

Comment: With the keyword `continue` you can skip the current loop cycle and start with the next one. Maybe this helps you solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [set a max timeout](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) on the Webdriver and then watch for `Timeout` exceptions in the loop:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

MAX_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 5

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(MAX_TIMEOUT_SECONDS)

for i in range(1, 201):
    try:
        url = "{base_url}?curpage={i}".format(base_url=base_url, i=i)
        driver.get(url)
    except TimeoutException:
        # skip this if it takes more than 5 seconds
        continue
    ... # process the scraped URL as usual
```

If a timeout occurs, the current iteration is skipped via `continue`.